# Wiki Formatting Help (This Could Happen On Any Webpage Though)

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

When you go to the webpage down below you will see the world Hi butting up next to the info box template, but I want it right underneath it.  This will happen on any page of the wiki.  I've already tried `<br />` but that only made it slide down a little.  If someone could help that would be great thanks.  I'm sure there is some CSS code I'm missing somewhere.

Here is the html if you would like to see it:

```
 <div style="background-color: {{color|{{{5}}}}}; color: white; width: {{{3}}}; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; float: left; height: {{{4}}}; margin: 5px;">
      <h3 style="color: white; border: solid 5px rgb(255,255,255); border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; background: {{color|{{{5}}}}};">{{{1}}}</h3>
      <p style="font-size:15px;">
           <b>{{{2}}}</b>
      </p>
 </div><noinclude>
 Hi
 </noinclude>
```

Thanks,
Jonathan

[Wiki Page In Need Of Help](http://jonathanpaczosa.com/wiki/index.php?title=Template%3aBox)

Comment: What is it you want to do? You haven't stated your problem. If you want the "Hi" to appear below the image, add clear:left or clear:both to the paragraph containing the text.

Comment: Questions with no real content that isn't on an external site (like this one) are not appropriate for StackOverflow. If the external site disappears or is unavailable, the question becomes meaningless. In addition, it's not searchable because the content isn't here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question, you are looking for `<br clear="all" />` instead of just `<br />`
I followed the link you posted, and it took me to a template with near identical coding other than you seem to be using some `{{color}}` template now and instead of `hi` you have `[[Category:Template]]`.  I hope that is the answer you are looking for.